# Multiplying multi-dimensional array by 1d array, to find nth product

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, matrix

I have a large 2d array list of matrices, for example
`matrices = np.random.rand(15, 10, 10)`

Each of the 15 matrices have 10X10 states (A-J).Each of the matrices are in order and represent time in years in increments of 1. Starting from `matrices[0]` which contains the matrix values for year 1, up to `matrices[14]` year 15.

The table below shows my an example of my customer data, I have 12000 customers.

```
customer| current_state | year  | amount
ax111   |   A           |   3   |  300
ax112   |   D           |   4   |  4890
ax113   |   G           |   9   |  624
```

I basically need to match each customers year to the correct matrix and place their amount in their current_state creating a vector for each customer.
Example:

`ax111 = np.array([300,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])` (amount 300 placed at state A, 1st element)

`ax112 = np([0,0,0,4890,0,0,0,0,0,0])` (amount 4890 placed at state D, 4th element)

I then need to multiply each customers array by the 2d array list `matrices`, based on the customers year, and continue multiplying the product by the next matrix until year 15, `matrices[14]` is reached for each customer.

The code below works for 1 customer, how can I run it for all 12000 customers.

```
matrices = np.random.rand(15, 10, 10)
ax111 = np.array([300,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
output = ax111
results = []
for arr in matrices[3:14]:
    output = output@arr
    results.append(output)
```

The output for the code above will be a (15,10,10) array list. How can I efficiently apply this to 12000 customers?

Comment: Read `np.matmul` to learn how to use `@` with n-d arrays.  Pay close attention to the different mixes of dimensions that it can handle.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for arr in matrices[3:15]`? Otherwise, where is the customer's year entering and why would you skip the last matrix?

Comment: Yes, thanks , I made a mistake, it should be [3:14]. Since it starts 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for each customer you perform the dot product of the corresponding array repeatedly with all matrices from `i=year` until `i=14`, you can precompute these accumulated matrices. I.e. instead of

```py
output = (((ax @ matrices[year]) @ matrices[year+1]) @ ...)
```

you can do

```py
output = ax @ (matrices[year] @ matrices[year+1]) @ ...)
```

and precompute the r.h.s.

Then you can perform a "pairwise matrix multiplication" (pairing each customer with the corresponding accumulated matrix) by performing a pairwise multiplication followed by a sum:

```py
import itertools as it
import numpy as np


# --- Example data ---
rng = np.random.default_rng()
matrices = rng.integers(0, 100, size=(15,10,10))  # using integers for exact results
customers = np.array([
    [300,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4890,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,624,0,0,0],
])
years = [3, 4, 9]


# --- Reference computation ---
results = []
for c, y in zip(customers, years):
    for m in matrices[y:]:
        c = c @ m
    results.append(c)
results = np.stack(results)


# --- Vectorized approach ---
matrices = np.stack([*it.accumulate(matrices[::-1], lambda x,y: y@x)][::-1])
new = (customers[:,:,None] * matrices[years]).sum(axis=1)


assert np.array_equal(new, results)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
The problem is I need each customers results in the form of an array list for each year multiplied.For example the output for ax112 will be an array list of (12,10,10) in size.Hence I can't sum them.Any other way of doing this?.

Comment: @noob100 As you can see from the above code example, the proposed solution produces the exact same results as your reference implementation (using the `for` loop); so if that is not what you want, you should update your question and be more precise with the description of the problem.

Comment: maybe I am misunderstanding, I am sorry if I am.
When I run your code and print results I get a (3,10,10) array list as the output.Its only giving me the 1st array for each customer. Am I doing something silly?

Comment: @noob100 In that case, what output shape do you expect? If you need all products from `year` through `14` then this isn't a constant number and hence can't be put in one array.

Comment: output shapes:
ax111 (12,10,10)
ax112 (11,10,10)
ax113(6,10,10)

It doesnt need to be in one array. As long as I have the products for each customer.

Comment: Right, as you can see, the first axis does not have constant size so it can't be in one array and hence can't be vectorized. So what's wrong with your approach then (the one presented in your question)?

Comment: I am trying to loop through all customers and get their products without having to manually change `for arr in matrices[3:14]`

Comment: Well you'd need `for arr in matrices[year:]` instead but that should be a trivial change.

Comment: a_guest I edited my loop to include `for arr in matrices[year:]` , but I am still having trouble looping through customers, can you please edit your answer and show me how to do it, pretty please.

Comment: Just look at the code in my answer and move `results.append(c)` into the inner `for` loop.